# how to view current user's facebook birthday notifications on graph api

Tags: ruby, facebook-graph-api

So I am currently making a Birthday App.

and when I use the Koala Facebook api graph I cannot get ahold of the current user's birthday connections. I can get all other notifications and some birthday announcements in the feed. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please, don't make the 10.000th birthday app. Facebook provides the functionality itself since years! What's the benefit?

Comment: oh it's going to use the wiki api and times api to find events that happened on the user's birthday then the ability to just paste the message on fb so you have a cool fb post for someone's birthday.

Answer (score 1):

You can only get the birthday of the authorized user, with the `user_birthday` permission. You can NOT get the birthdays of his friends, friend permissions have been removed.

Meaning, a birthday App would only make sense between authorized users.